# Eiffel: REAL_32.to_double gives a strange value

Tags: eiffel

Trying to transform a real_32 to real_64, I'm getting

```
real_32: 61.55
real_64: 61.54999923706055
```

Am I wrong with the `to_double` function?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). In the particular example, the binary representation of the decimal 61.55 with single and double precision respectively is:

```
REAL_32: 0    10000100 11101100011001100110011
REAL_64: 0 10000000100 1110110001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
```

As you can see, the trailing pattern `0011` is recurrent and should go *ad infinitum* to give a precise value.

When `REAL_32` is assigned to `REAL_64`, the trailing `0011`s are not added automatically, but filled with zeroes instead:

```
REAL_32: 0    10000100 11101100011001100110011
REAL_64: 0 10000000100 1110110001100110011001100000000000000000000000000000
```

In decimal notation, this corresponds to `61.54999923706055`. What is essential here, `61.54999923706055` and `61.55` have exactly the same binary representation when using single precision floating numbers. You can check it yourself with `print ({REAL_32} 61.55 = {REAL_32} 61.54999923706055)`. In other words, the results you get are *correct*, and the two values are the same. The only difference is that when `REAL_32` is printed, it is rounded to lower number of meaningful decimal digits.

This is the reason why accounting and bookkeeping software never uses floating-point numbers, only integer and decimal.

Comment: Thx for the explanation I learned a lot, is there a way to solve that with Eiffel? you mentioned integer and decimal... I still don't see how to solve this issue even if it is expected

Comment: @Pipo If the original value always comes as a decimal number with known precision, either an integer with a scaling factor or a decimal number can represent it without loosing precision. This is known as [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Comment: thx which classes of eiffel should I use for decimal and floating-point?

Comment: Giving me the explanation doesn't give me the solution how to transform a real_32 to a real_64 without having this issue...

Comment: @Pipo There is no way to transform real_32 to real_64 without having the issue. If it's important to keep a specified precision, decimal arithmetic should be used instead. For example, the class `DECIMAL` from the library `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

As a **workaround** working for getting from JSON into typescript deserialization, the following worked:

```
 a_real_32.out.to_real_64
```

Comment: This may or may not work, depending on a particular input value. BTW, you are reading the number to make some operations on it, not just to output it immediately, right? Just try the "workaround" with some operation, e.g. `a_real_32.out.to_real_64 + 0.01` to see what's going on.